# solving large number of equations with python

Tags: python, scipy

I writing a finite element program and want to solve a system of non-linear equations with scipy root finder. The equation is Ax-B=0 and A is a (2000, 2000) array for example. So it takes a long time for root finder to compute jacobian and then solve the equation. How can I speed up the solving process.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  What things have you tried?  You'll get better results if you follow [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to asking questions. Posting your code would allow others to more easily suggest ways to improve it.

Comment: The question is too open ended to get a useful answer. How to speed up your problem depends entirely on your systems of PDEs as the optimal method will depend on things like the sparsity and conditioning of your matrix A. That said, some starting points are newton krylov solvers (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton_krylov.html) and gmres (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.gmres.html).